# Is the "congiuntivo" used after this verb?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> "Da quel che si dice pare che Monica **sia** o **è** innamorata di Nino."

Which is correct here, the "indicativo" or the "congiuntivo"?

Comment: Il congiuntivo e' corretto. Si usa dopo verbi come sembrare o apparire. Purtroppo l'indicativo viene sempre più usato al posto del congiuntivo.

Comment: And it's also used with the verb "parere" with an impersonal form, that is the one which appears in your sentence.

Comment: This link may help: http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/english/italian-grammar/expressions_which_use_subjunctive_form.htm

Comment: Si confermo, pochi italiani usano i congiuntivi quando in realtà servirebbero... La lingua si sta facendo più semplice di tempo fa. Ormai non ci viene quasi neanche corretto nei compiti di italiano!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subjunctive is used after impersonal constructions with verbs which express uncertainty such as

> - *pare che*
> - *sembra che*
> - *può darsi che*

So, the most correct way to write your sentence would be

> "Da quel che si dice pare che Monica sia innamorata di Nino."

Answer (score 1):

You should use the subjunctive to convey uncertainty in your opinion, or in someone else's opinion.
Ex: "Non sono sicuro che mio fratello sia andato a scuola"
    "Dicono che sia un ottimo film"