# Definitive listing for when to use the Italian subjunctive

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Can someone tell me of a definitive listing to determine what verbs/terms/phrases require the Italian subjunctive to be used? For example, if I didn't know that *magari* required the congiuntivo, I don't see how I would learn that by looking it up in references such as [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/magari/), [Collins/WR](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/magari), Il Ragazzini, etc. Maybe it's listed there but I need to be instructed in how to see it?

Of course, it's easy to find sites which list cases where the congiuntivo is used, and I've seen questions on this site like [this one](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/is-the-congiuntivo-used-after-this-verb), which refer to what seem to be good lists [like this one](http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/english/italian-grammar/verbs_which_use_subjunctive_form.htm). But what I'm looking for is something more reliable, a reference. Do I have to just rely on whoever's posted the longest list?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that to give a completely exhaustive answer to this question would be quite complicated. See also [this answer](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10545/).

Comment: This would require a couple of chapters in a book.

Comment: Thanks @egreg but I'm not looking for an explanation, but rather a list, or perhaps an indication in a reference such as is seen for transitive/intransitive verbs, etc.

Comment: Sometimes there is also variation among regions or levels of formality. For example, "non so se è il caso"/"non so se sia il caso" are both used in spoken Italian. The first one is maybe slightly more common. In "good" writing, where people tend to follow prescriptive rules, you would write "non so se sia il caso". But if you were writing your friend and you said "non so se è il caso", it sounds fine, unlike something definitely wrong (i.e. doesn't exist in descriptive grammar), such as "*non penso è il caso".